# how to access the non state variale updated value, in functional component.?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I have to react variable, let's call it `temp`, it's not a state variable but a normal let variable.

the problem is that I am not able to get the updated value in the render.
I know it's not a state variable so it won't rerender the UI, whenever the variable is updated.

but, I am not accessing the variable until the variable is set.

ex: ->

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
   let temp;
       const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
   init = () => {
      setLoading(true);
      temp = "updated value";
      setLoading(false);
   }
   useEffect(() => {
       init();
    }, [])
   return (
      {laoding ? <div>loading</div> : <div> {temp}</div>}
   )
}
```

in the above code, if the loading is false and the temp variable is set, then the UI should reflect the updated value.
but, it's not,

it works fine in-class components.

am I missing something here?

Comment: i dont see you calling init anywhere. the temp variable will be reset regardless, because your rerender (changing of loading) causes the function code to rerun entirely, and that means temp will be created anew. if you want to get something as close to an instance variable in a function you want to use `useRef` for it.

Comment: sorry, updated the code.

Comment: my description above stands. the execution here is: 
component renders => mounts => use effect runs => state is changed => rerenders => temp is newly created as undefined let. use `useRef` for temp and assign `temp.current = ...` in init. it guarantees to persist through renders.

Comment: I got it, that the issue is when it rerenders the temp is reset, :(, could you provide the code example with useRef as you are suggesting

Comment: added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the effect for the functional components. `useEffect` gets triggered every time its dependency changes which will trigger rerender for you.

However, I can't see the real use of the init variable. So assuming you want to set value during component mount. I think it'll look like the below.

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
   let temp;
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

   useEffect(() => {
    // Empty array means that this will be executed when component mounts
    init()
   }, [])

   useEffect(() => {
    // Rerender will be triggered whenever temp gets changed
   }, [temp])

   const init = () => {
      setLoading(true);
      temp = "updated value";
      setLoading(false);
   }

   return (
      <>
        {
            loading ? <span>loading...</span> : <span>{temp}</span>
        }
      </>
   )
}
```

NOTE: I'd still go with storing temp as a state in this case because it's the part of react's system and that's how it should be used.

Comment: yes, but why it won't work without rerendering manually. 
we are showing the "loading" until the temp is set. 
and when we remove the loading, then it will cause the rerender, and after that, the updated temp value should be shown.

Comment: this, pattern works in-class component, but not here

Answer (score 1):

the execution here is: component renders => mounts => use effect runs => state is changed => rerenders => temp is newly created as undefined let. use `useRef` for temp and assign `temp.current = ...` in init. it guarantees to persist through renders.

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const temp = useRef();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const init = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    temp.current = "updated value";
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, []);

  return <>{loading ? <div>loading</div> : <div>{temp.current}</div>}</>;
};
```